# Permutation on array of type "Location", from GoogleMapsAPI NuGet Package

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, google-maps, permutation

this is my very first post here on StackOverflow so please tell me if I did anything wrong, also english is not my native language, forgive me if there is any gramatical errors.

My question is how can I permutate the items of an array of type "Location", I need to get all possible permutations of waypoints given by the user to then calculate the best route based on time or distance. (I don't want to use the normal route calculation)

I've searched for algorithms but all of them when I put the array of type "Location[]" in the function's parameter I get the error that the object needs to be IEnumerable and I don't know how to convert to that if is even possible, I never worked with IEnumerable.

If it is of any help this is my code for calculating the route:

```
    //Gets the waypoints from a listBox provided by the user, "mode" selects between best time and best distance
    //backgroundworker so the UI dont freezes, and return the optimal waypoint order
    public Location[] CalcularRota(Location[] waypoints, int mode, BackgroundWorker work, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Declarations
        string origem = "";
        string destino = "";
        Rota[] prop = new Rota[100]; //this index is the number of times the algorithm will be executed, more equals accuracy but much more time to complete
        Rota bestDist = new Rota();
        Rota bestTime = new Rota();
        DirectionService serv = new DirectionService();
        DirectionRequest reqs = new DirectionRequest();
        DirectionResponse resp;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Location[] rndWays;
        int dist = 0;
        int ti = 0;

        bestDist.Distance = 1000000000; //put higher values for the first comparation to be true (end of code)
        bestTime.Time = 1000000000;

        if (waypoints != null)
        {
            reqs.Sensor = false;
            reqs.Mode = TravelMode.driving;               

            for (int i = 0; i < prop.Length; i++) //initializes prop
                prop[i] = new Rota();

            for (int i = 0; i < prop.Length; i++)
            {
                rndWays = waypoints.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray(); //randomizes the order, I want to get all permutations and then test
                                                                        //but I dont know how so I've been using randomized
                dist = ti = 0;
                origem = prop[0].ToString();  //save this particular waypoint's origin and destination
                destino = prop[1].ToString();

                reqs.Origin = origem;
                reqs.Destination = destino;

                if (waypoints.Length > 0)
                    reqs.Waypoints = rndWays;

                resp = serv.GetResponse(reqs); //request the route with X order of waypoints to google

                if (resp.Status == ServiceResponseStatus.Ok) //wait the response otherwise the program crashes
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < resp.Routes[0].Legs.Length; j++) //gets the distance and time of this particular order
                    {
                        ti += int.Parse(resp.Routes[0].Legs[j].Duration.Value);
                        dist += int.Parse(resp.Routes[0].Legs[j].Distance.Value);
                    }
                }

                prop[i].Origem = origem;  //saves this waypoints order details for further comparison
                prop[i].Destino = destino;
                prop[i].Distance = dist;
                prop[i].Time = ti;
                prop[i].Order = rndWays;

                work.ReportProgress(i); //report the progress
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < prop.Length; i++) //gets the best distance and time
            {
                if (bestDist.Distance > prop[i].Distance)
                {
                    bestDist.Distance = prop[i].Distance;
                    bestDist.Time = prop[i].Time;
                    bestDist.Order = prop[i].Order;
                    bestDist.Origem = prop[i].Origem;
                    bestDist.Destino = prop[i].Destino;
                }
                if (bestTime.Time > prop[i].Time)
                {
                    bestTime.Distance = prop[i].Distance;
                    bestTime.Time = prop[i].Time;
                    bestTime.Order = prop[i].Order;
                    bestTime.Origem = prop[i].Origem;
                    bestTime.Destino = prop[i].Destino;
                }
            }

            if (bestDist.Order == bestTime.Order) //if the same waypoint order has the same time and distance
                return bestDist.Order;            // returns whatever bestDist.Order or bestTime.Order
            else if (bestDist.Order != bestTime.Order) //if different returns corresponding to the mode selected
            {
                if (mode == 1) return bestDist.Order;
                if (mode == 2) return bestTime.Order;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What I want is to permutate the waypoints given and test each permutation, I've been struggling with this for a time, if u guys could help me with any way possible would be great.

Ty.

EDIT.

I found this function here on StackOverflow:

```
   public static bool NextPermutation<T>(T[] elements) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        var count = elements.Length;

        var done = true;

        for (var i = count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            var curr = elements[i];

            // Check if the current element is less than the one before it
            if (curr.CompareTo(elements[i - 1]) < 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // An element bigger than the one before it has been found,
            // so this isn't the last lexicographic permutation.
            done = false;

            // Save the previous (bigger) element in a variable for more efficiency.
            var prev = elements[i - 1];

            // Have a variable to hold the index of the element to swap
            // with the previous element (the to-swap element would be
            // the smallest element that comes after the previous element
            // and is bigger than the previous element), initializing it
            // as the current index of the current item (curr).
            var currIndex = i;

            // Go through the array from the element after the current one to last
            for (var j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
            {
                // Save into variable for more efficiency
                var tmp = elements[j];

                // Check if tmp suits the "next swap" conditions:
                // Smallest, but bigger than the "prev" element
                if (tmp.CompareTo(curr) < 0 && tmp.CompareTo(prev) > 0)
                {
                    curr = tmp;
                    currIndex = j;
                }
            }

            // Swap the "prev" with the new "curr" (the swap-with element)
            elements[currIndex] = prev;
            elements[i - 1] = curr;

            // Reverse the order of the tail, in order to reset it's lexicographic order
            for (var j = count - 1; j > i; j--, i++)
            {
                var tmp = elements[j];
                elements[j] = elements[i];
                elements[i] = tmp;
            }

            // Break since we have got the next permutation
            // The reason to have all the logic inside the loop is
            // to prevent the need of an extra variable indicating "i" when
            // the next needed swap is found (moving "i" outside the loop is a
            // bad practice, and isn't very readable, so I preferred not doing
            // that as well).
            break;
        }

        // Return whether this has been the last lexicographic permutation.
        return done;
    }
```

The usage is:

```
    NextPermutation(array);
```

Doing this and putting my array (rndWays) as overload I get the following error:

The type 'Google.Maps.Location' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Form1.NextPermutation< T >(T[])'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Google.Maps.Location' to 'System.IComparable< Google.Maps.Location >'.

Comment: Array's in C# should implement IEnumerable. Could you provide specific code to show the error?

Comment: Added the permutation algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Location does not implement the IComparable interface.

Change:

```
 public static bool NextPermutation<T>(T[] elements) where T : IComparable<T>
```

to:

```
 public static bool NextPermutation(Location[] elements)
```

And replace each CompareTo() with your own comparison function.